# Does Azure SDK 2.1 and Visual Studio 2010 official retirement mean deployments are no longer allowed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

We have an .Net 4.0 Azure Cloud Service application that is using Azure SDK 2.1. There is apparently some kind of "official retirement" of this last version of the SDK that support Visual Studio 2010 as stated in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479282.aspx .

What does official retirement mean? Are we able to still deploy to staging if there is already an app in production for Azure Cloud Service? Or are we being forced to move to the newer Visual Studio 2015 IDE?

We are using the latest “Operating System Family” which is Windows Server 2012 R2 and have “Operating System Version” at “Automatic”.